# Getting Exception while connecting Spring to hibernate using H2 database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting below exception:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.naveen.java.InsertTest.main(InsertTest.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:508)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:677)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection timed out: connect Nested exception: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:499)
    ... 16 more
```

Below is employee .java

```
package com.naveen.java;

import javax.persistence.Id;

public class Employee {

private int id;
private String name;
private int salary;
private String LASTNAME ;

public String getLASTNAME() {
    return LASTNAME;
}
public void setLASTNAME(String lASTNAME) {
    this.LASTNAME = lASTNAME;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public float getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

}

below is employeedao.java

```
package com.naveen.java;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

public class EmployeeDao {
HibernateTemplate template;
public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}

public void saveEmployee(Employee e){
    template.save(e);
}

public void updateEmployee(Employee e){
    template.update(e);
}

public void deleteEmployee(Employee e){
    template.delete(e);
}
}
```

below is inserttest.java

```
package com.naveen.java;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class InsertTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext con=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    //Resource r=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
    EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)con.getBean("d");

    Employee e=new Employee();
    e.setId(147);
    e.setName("kumar");
    e.setSalary(70000);

    //dao.saveEmployee(e);
    dao.updateEmployee(e);
}
}
```

below are both the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  


   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value="123"/>
    </bean> 


<bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
         <list>
        <value>employee-hbm.xml</value>  
         </list>
        </property>  

       <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="d" class="com.naveen.EmployeeDao">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
    </bean>  </beans>
```

2nd xml mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.naveen.java.Employee" table="EMP558">

      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="firstName" column="NAME" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="LASTNAME" type="string"/>
      <property name="salary" column="salary" type="double"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have tried to link through JDBC and it's working fine.

Comment: Where u keep "employee-hbm.xml"? Check whether this path for employee-hbm.xml is not wrong.

Comment: @arin Both are present in the same package/folder.

Comment: Can you verify if your applicationContext.xml is correct? I am getting error http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp. It seems </beans> end tag is missing

Comment: Hi, what hibernate version you're using now?

Comment: @Reddy Sorry for typo i missed it ..

Comment: @kucing_terbang  hibernate 3

Comment: If you were able to solve the problem, can you please post it here?

Answer (score 0):

salary field has int type, but there is double in the hibernate mapping

Comment: Still no progress.

Thanks for help

Comment: please update the question to reflect the changes you have done

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused because the hibernate trying retrieving the dtd file. so, the workaround could be :

1. change the value of the dtd from that to `"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"`
2. Create your own function to parse the configuration then passed to the hibernate like this

   ```
   public static Document parseConfiguration(String resourcePath) throws Exception { 
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
        factory.setValidating(false); <-- the magic is here
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
        return builder.parse(builder.getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)); 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the error you are getting, though I fixed lot of errors in your entity (properties defined in the mapping file not present in the entity). I have reached the step where it is trying to insert the record, so I am well past the stage where you are getting the error.

By looking into the hibernate source file (`org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:499)`) which is throwing error, hibernate is not able to reach your mapping xml file.

Please double check if the mapping file is at proper location and also readable.
Also make sure you have correct version of hibernate jar in the classpath.

Comment: i Know there are some mistakes but I tried with a single column  still in my case i m getting the same exception again and again..


Can u share ur which hibernate jar and dtd u r using ...it will be a great help..

Comment: I have copied your code only (including your package structure). I am using hibernate 3.6.1. Can you check if you are able to connect to the mapping DTD http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd?

Comment: It looks like some configuration issue. Did you check if you can access DTD directly? Also did you check if you have correct hibernate jar in the class path?

If it is only simple project, you may want to freshly do it again.